# displaying the value of variable that is inside while loop on to the TextArea

Tags: java

I am trying to convert speech to text and to display it on an AWT textArea.
But the output in the speech to text converter function is generated inside a while loop and I am unable to display that on the textArea. I am getting a null pointer exception; please someone help.

```
public class Speechrec  {

    private static TextArea textArea;
    String resultText;
    private String dr;

    public void recognizer(String[] args) {

        try {
            URL url;
            if (args.length > 0) {
                url = new File(args[0]).toURI().toURL();
            } 
            else {
                url = Speechrec.class.getResource("speechrec.config.xml");
            }    
            System.out.println("Loading...");    
            ConfigurationManager cm = new ConfigurationManager(url);    
            Recognizer recognizer = (Recognizer) cm.lookup("recognizer");
            Microphone microphone = (Microphone) cm.lookup("microphone");    
            /* allocate the resource necessary for the recognizer */
            recognizer.allocate();    
            /* the microphone will keep recording until the program exits */
            if (microphone.startRecording()) {    
            System.out.println("Say: some greetings");
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Start speaking. Press Ctrl-C to quit.\n");

                Result result = recognizer.recognize();

                if (result != null) {
                    String resultText = result.getBestFinalResultNoFiller();            
                    textArea.setText(resultText);
                } 
                else {
                    System.out.println("I can't hear what you said.\n");
                }
            }
            } 
            else {
               System.out.println("Cannot start microphone.");
               recognizer.deallocate();
               System.exit(1);
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception) {                
            // exception handling
        }
    }        

public static void main( final String[] args) throws IOException {
    Speechrec sp1=new Speechrec();      
    Frame frame=new Frame("speech to sign language converter");
    TextArea textarea=new TextArea (05,30);     
    Button button = new Button("Start speaking"); 
    // ...        
    frame.add(button,BorderLayout.SOUTH); 
    // ...
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.TRAILING,50,15));
    frame.setSize(500,400); 
    frame.setVisible(true);

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {           
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e1) {      
             Speechrec sp=new Speechrec();
         sp.recognizer(args);
          }});
    }    
}
```

Comment: What is the question *exactly*? Please provide minimal compleable code that is relevant to the *specific* issue at hand.

Comment: Please post the **relevant** part of your code (see also http://sscce.org).

Comment: man... of course you are getting a null pointer exception. textArea is null, isn't it? There's a difference between textarea and textArea. You have two text areas: one in your main method (that was your initial problem) and another one outside that you don't initialize. So it is null.

Comment: i want output to be displayed on textarea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your text area as a private static field in your class. Then you can access it in easily like `textArea.setText("something");`

```
private static TextArea textArea;

public static void main( final String[] args) throws IOException{
    Speechrec sp1 = new Speechrec();
    textArea = new TextArea(sp1.dr,05,30);
    Button button = new Button("Start speaking");
    // and so on...
}

while (true) {

        Result result = recognizer.recognize();

        if (result != null) {

            String resultText = result.getBestFinalResultNoFiller();

            dr = resultText;

            textArea.setText(resultText);

            // or:

            textArea.append(resultText);
        } 
}
```

In the next step you should move all code that creates your UI into the constructor of your class. That would be a cleaner solution.

Comment: if it solves your problem vote up and mark it as the correct answer ;)

Comment: He won't ever come back here.

Comment: actually now i am getting following exceptions
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at sts.Speechrec.recognizer(Speechrec.java:69)
 at sts.Speechrec$1.actionPerformed(Speechrec.java:155)
 at java.awt.Button.processActionEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Button.processEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
 so on.. :(

Comment: He will, the problems don't end... ;)

Comment: What code is in line 69 of your Speechrec class? What code in line 155? Have you initialized textArea?

Comment: at line 69 i am trying to display resultText on textArea

Comment: on textArea? not textarea? (two different objects!) AND IS IT INITIALIZED? or is it null?

Answer (score 0):

Because recognizer run until you quit program. If you want to update textarea, you must set your update code in a thread that can interact with Gui. example.

```
 public void update(String s){
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
         public void run(){
           textArea.append(s);
              }// end run
             });//end Runnable
              }// end method
```